# Android Sqlite Order by number then letter then emptyString or null

Tags: android, sqlite

So I have a query that return number, letter and empty string
with

```
 order by lower table.thecolumn
```

and return me as this order which is right

-empty string

-number

-letter

but I want them to order by

-number

-letter

-empty

Is there anyways I can achieve this with sqlite query or through codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY coalesce(length(table.thecolumn),0) = 0, lower(table.thecolumn)
```

There:

- `length(table.thecolumn)` - returns `0` if `table.thecolumn` is empty; if `table.thecolumn` is `NULL` then `coalesce(...,0)` returns 0
- so condition `coalesce(length(table.thecolumn),0) = 0` returns `1` for empty or `NULL` values and `0` - for not empty.
- so empty values will be sorted at the end